# Justification greatest common divisor?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let A,B,C be natural numbers. 
Let M be a natural number.

*Proposition*

**A divide B if and only If the least common multiple of A and B is B.**

I am not sure how demonstrate this.

It seem by my intuition true. Because if A divide B then a is a factor of B,because the least common multiple of B is B.

Then A can reach B by multiplying by something smaller than B.

But how do I make my argument stronger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The least common multiple of $A$ and $B$ is at least $\max(A,B)$ hence, if $A$ divides $B$ then $A\leq B$ then both $A$ and $B$ divide the smallest possible thing the LCM could be, and so the LCM is the smallest thing it could possibly be: $\max(A,B)=B$.

Note you also have to prove that if the LCM of $A$ and $B$ is $B$ then $A$ divides $B$.

Comment: I see it is both you have to prove it both ways and they are quite similar methods of proving

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\ \ \ a\mid b\!\!\!\! &&\iff a\,\Bbb Z \supseteq b\,\Bbb Z\\
&& \iff  a\,\Bbb Z \cap b\,\Bbb Z\, =\, b\,\Bbb Z\\
&& \iff {\rm lcm}(a,b)\, =\, b\end{eqnarray}$